# john ripper and option --mask

Tags: john-the-ripper

I have a text file `parole.txt` containing the dictionary to be passed to john with the `--wordlist` option.

Here is an extract of the file

```
mamma
papa
libro
...
...
```

if I use the `--mask=?u?w?d` option I get the following

```
Amamma0
Bmamma0
Cmamma0
....
Alibro0
Blibro0
Clibro0
```

and this is NOT what I'm looking for. I would like to capitalize the first letter of the single words:

```
Mamma1
Mamma2
Mamma3
Mamma4
...
...
Libro1
Libro2
libro3
```

I can't find a way to point this out to John. I'm sure the solution is before my eyes, but I can't find it.

Comment: Have you looked at using a wordlist rule: Using Az"#" may give you the result you need...

Comment: @RoryAlsop that would do the first example, which is what the OP doesn't want. It appends `Az` to the beginning of every output

Comment: I think what you want is the `c` mask: "capitalise"

Comment: Ahh - I think I saw an earlier version of the post where it looked like they were asking how to append a digit. My bad :-)